# Java custom event handler and listeners

Tags: java, events, socket.io, listener, netty

I'm currently playing around with a Java implementation of Socket.io, available here: [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio)

I've got the server up and running, and its receiving/sending messages nicely between client and server, but I need to have events trigger on certain messages being received, and that's where I'm confused.

Here's my code:

```
server.addEventListener("message", clientData.class, new DataListener<clientData>() {
    @Override
    public void onData(SocketIOClient client, clientData data, AckRequest ackRequest) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Message from client: " + data.getMessage());

    }
});


public class ClientData{

    String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Essentially what I'd like to happen is when a particular message is received from a client, I need a function within another class to run.  I've spent the last two hours reading about `Observable`, `Observer`, `Interfaces` and event handlers, but I'm really not sure how to set this up.

The library also makes mention of this `DataListener`, but I've no idea what that is, as there's little documentation in the library.

Any input or advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. The println is not called? Any exceptions? And please make the clientData class start with upper case.

Comment: No the println is called, but I need another class to be notified that this has happened.  I thought that was the point of the event listeners?

Comment: Yes. And that's exactly what you have in the code. The listener is the anonymous class implementing DataListener.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let's say your class that raises the event is called `A`. And the class that needs to listen for the event is called `B`. And the event is called `SomeEvent`.

First, create an interface called `SomeEventListener`:

```
public interface SomeEventListener {
    void onSomeEvent ();
}
```

If there are arguments that you want to pass when the event occurs (typically something about the event), you can add it to the method.

Then in `A`, you add a field:

```
private SomeEventListener listener;
```

and a method:

```
public void setSomeEventListener (SomeEventListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

This way, `B` can call `setSomeEventListener` to set the listener.

When the event occurs, `A` should call

```
if (listener != null) listener.onSomeEvent ();
```

And that's all there is to `A`!

In `B`, you need to implement the interface:

```
public class B implements SomeEventListener {
    public void onSomeEvent () {
        //do whatever you like when SomeEvent happens.
    }
}
```

And you can listen for `SomeEvent` like this:

```
someInstanceOfA.setSomeEventListener (this);
```

And after this call, all the `SomeEvent` raised by `A` can be listened by `B`!

Using the Observable and Observer pattern, we can see that `A` is an Observable and `B` is an Observer.

That's easy!

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anything about Socket.io. The above is just a general implementation of events and listeners.

Comment: Simple as that!  Thanks very much man, I was trying this last night and I could not get my head around it.  That's doing exactly what I need now, thanks again man!!