# Java - Create a Custom event and listener

Tags: java, events, listener

I am trying to make a custom event and listener in Java. I already looked at these articles and questions:

[Create a custom event in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270132/create-a-custom-event-in-java)

[Java custom event handler and listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948916/java-custom-event-handler-and-listeners/33950694)

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077333/core-java/mr-happy-object-teaches-custom-events.html

But I still can't really wrap my head around it. This is what I want done:

I have a `String` object whose content changes as the program runs. I want to be able to add a listener to the string which listens wether it contains a specific string and when it does run a piece of code. I want to use it like this:

```
String string = "";
//String.addListener() and textListener need to be created
string.addListener(new textListener("hello world") {
    @Override
    public void onMatch(
         System.out.println("Hello world detected");
    )
}

//do a bunch of stuff

string = "The text Hello World is used by programmers a lot"; //the string contains "Hello World", so the listener will now print out "Hello world detected"
```

I know there might be easier ways of doing this, but I would like to know how to do it this way.

Thank you @Marcos Vasconcelos for pointing out that you cannot add methods to a `String` object, so is there a way I can use a custom class like @Ben pointed out?

Comment: You cannot add methods to String, you can add to the class you use it

Comment: You could do this with Kotlin and its extensions.  A wrapper class and a Java 101 tutorial on events should do it in Java.

Comment: You can create your own class `EventString` (or something else), have a String object in there and then implement a custom Event Listener for it.

Comment: @Ben And how do I implement a custom Event Listener? As I said I still don't really understand it after reading mutliple questions and articles

Comment: Basically, event listeners are not magic. In order for listeners to work, you need to program a mechanism that triggers the events when changes happen. That is, you can't allow the program to directly assign to the string - you have to do it through that mechanism.

Comment: It's a simple two fold process. You need some interface `MyEventListener` with a method `onMyEvent`. Then you have a `addMyEventListener(MyEventListener)` in your `EventString` class that holds references to the listeners. And when whatever you want to happen happens (e.g. in your `setValue` method the value `hello world` is the parameter) you call the `onMyEvent` method for your listeners.

Comment: But that's perfectly explained in the posts you linked so no reason to repeat all of that here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I made a minimal example maybe that will help you:

You need an interface for your listener:

```
public interface MyEventListener
{
    public void onMyEvent();
}
```

Then for your String you need some wrapper class that also handles your events

```
public class EventString
{
    private String                  myString;

    private List<MyEventListener>   eventListeners;

    public EventString(String myString)
    {
        this.myString = myString;
        this.eventListeners = new ArrayList<MyEventListener>();
    }

    public void addMyEventListener(MyEventListener evtListener)
    {
        this.eventListeners.add(evtListener);
    }

    public void setValue(String val)
    {
        myString = val;

        if (val.equals("hello world"))
        {
            eventListeners.forEach((el) -> el.onMyEvent());
        }
    }
}
```

You see that the `myString` field is private and only accessible using the `setValue` method. This is so we can see when our event condition triggers.

And then you only need some implementation of this, such as:

```
EventString temp = new EventString("test");

temp.addMyEventListener(() -> {
    System.out.println("hello world detected");
});

temp.setValue("hello world");
```

Comment: is there a way to not check whenever you call `setValue` but to check continuously? Maybe with a while loop?

Comment: You can trigger the event whenever you want. Just use the `eventListeners.forEach((el) -> el.onMyEvent());` line.